# Preserve shortcuts in SSMS after restart

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, ssms

I use SQL Server Management Studio in this version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    14.0.17289.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools  14.0.1016.283
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                           3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer               9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                  4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                          6.3.18363
```

[image]

I want to define a custom shortcut for closing a tab, I've set it up like this:

> Tools => Options => Environment => Keyboard => Keybord => I removed Ctrl + W shortcut from all commands => I assigned Ctrl + W for command "Window.CloseDocumentWindow"

The result looks like this:

[image]

When I press ok, Ctrt + W works fine as expected. The problem is when I restart SSMS, the shortcut Ctrl + W is no longed assigned to the command, so I have to assign it again to make it work like I want. That's of course annoying.

**How to preserve shortcuts after SSMS restart?**

Comment: Using version 18.6, the shortcut persists after restarting SSMS. Update yours or try to repair it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you, I'll have a look into it. Unfortunately, I also use some add-ins that work only in this particular version of SMSS, that's mostly the reason why I'm using this older version.